# updating columns with a sequence number mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table with the columns: (this is only an example I have 50K records)

```
Name,   Number

Joe     Null
Michael Null
Moses   Null
```

I to update the number with a sequence number from 1-3 so it will look like this:

```
Name,   Number

Joe     1
Michael 2
Moses   3
```

How can I do it in SQL for Mysql in one SQL command

Comment: What's the supposed order based on?  Alphabetical?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I need to have in numbers all the numbers from 1-3 (1-size)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
SET @rank:=0;
update T
set Number=@rank:=@rank+1;
```

**UPDATE**

alternative way with one statement

```
UPDATE T
JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) r
SET Number=@rank:=@rank+1;
```

Comment: btw, you can add `ORDER BY NAME` to that update if required :)

Comment: When I run above query, I get Data Truncated For Column... error

Comment: @LearnMore which data type of that column?

Comment: @triclosan : Column data type is BIGINT(11).

Comment: @Bohemian: Maybe this is new since 2011 but actually you can't add an `ORDER BY` because it's a multi-table update. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384104/1754243) gets around the issue, though.

Comment: Your Solution works smooth ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could try setting the `Number` to AUTO_INCREMENT so the numbers will be generated:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY Number INT AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Other than that, you probably need:
a) stored routines
b) application code

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks. (Although I did have to say 'ALTER TABLE table MODIFY COLUMN column int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;' in order for it to work. Maybe a version thing.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled to find an answer online and found the following method worked for me, based on some of the info above but with a different update approach. Posting here in case it helps others too.

Note: for my dataset, the rank is a one-time fixed calculation, it won't change. I wanted to add it as a column to save running a computation each time I pull the data from MySQL into Python.

Solution I used:

- set rank to 0 (as above)
- create a temporary table containing the select query to compute the rank
- update the original table with the computed ranks.

Sample names used, rowid is the unique identifier for each row, value is the metric that will be used to determine the rank for each row

```
SET @rank=0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE rank_temp
AS
(SELECT rowid, value, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank FROM source_table ORDER BY value ASC);

UPDATE sourcetable a, rank_temp b
SET a.rank = b.rank
WHERE a.rowid = b.rowid;
```

It's a crude method but has worked on my dataset.

Comment: sometimes gems can be found insider crude code , very useful in my case , wonderful attempt indeed

Answer (score 0):

```
update `table_name` set `Number`=@rank:=@rank+1
```

This will be done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using above two solutions I made this query and it worked.

SET @rank=0;update emp_data set empfk_id = @rank:=@rank+1;