# Mysql Insert Order Number By VARCHAR Field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question about inserting row order number by spesific order type.

Products table has OrderNumber field. I want to programaticly add new line to appropriate OrderNumber by its name. If the reference column would be integer it has to be easy like that

```
update products set OrderNumber=OrderNumber+1 where Price>555
```

Is there similar way for varchar field like

```
update products set OrderNumber=OrderNumber+1 where Name>'bla%'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can use STRCMP('text', 'text2')</strike>

```
update products 
set OrderNumber=OrderNumber+1 
where STRCMP(Name, 'bla') = 1;
```

I missunderstood your point. Can you try something like this?

```
SET @rownum:=0;
update 
set OrderNumber=@rownum:=@rownum + 1
from products
order by Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply run an update query with a sequential number like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617056/updating-columns-with-a-sequence-number-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad design. Why not simply have a plain-jane auto_increment field and order by that? Every new record would by defnition have a higher ID than any of its predecessors.

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like `update products set OrderNumber=OrderNumber+1 where Name like 'bla%'`

Comment: yes. but if added product name is book then it doesn't work properly    update products set OrderNumber=OrderNumber+1 where Name like 'b%'. because ball has to be before than book

Comment: if i understood well you need to update the table and set the OrderNumber+1 to all the rows that are before 'bla..' ??

Comment: yes. i actualy don't want to do it by loop for refresh all rows. but it has to, be i understant

Comment: I think you need to index all your rows with an id compaired to the alphabetical meaning of your need.Then simply select all the ones that are less than the letters you need. I must admit it's a tough question :)

Comment: no i don't deal with the great idea:) count question just monday's syndrome

Comment: can this help ? update products set OrderNumber=OrderNumber+1 where SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, 'bla', -1) ASC
found the function here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6315/discussion-between-user305015-and-themhz)