# Update one field so that the order value will be continuous

Tags: php, mysql

In my table one field "ord" that contains the order of the values for a particular group.

tbl_test and the fields are Group,time,ord,name

Sample entries

```
id       Group time                      ord          name
----------------------------------------------------------------
1        1     1340865990                1            john
2        1     1340865880                2            jos
3        1     1340867830                3            mery
4        1     1340867830                4            bill
5        1     1340867830                5            stiev
6        1     1340867830                6            tom
7        2     1340867830                1            test
8        3     1340867830                2            john
```

If I remove a set of values  from group 1 for example I removed "mery" and "tom" then the "ord" field must have an updated order value for the remaining items as

```
id       Group time                      ord          name
----------------------------------------------------------------
1        1     1340865990                1            john
2        1     1340865880                2            jos
4        1     1340867830                3            bill
5        1     1340867830                4            stiev
```

The item that are removed may be of any order. To remove the item the user will give a list of ids and the group.

How can I implement this in mysql?

Note :

To update the ord when a single entry is deleted I am using the following query:

```
SET @a = 3;
UPDATE tbl_test 
SET ord = 5,time = 1337690755 
WHERE Group = 1 AND id = 6;
```

Comment: you've also updated the id of bill and stiev, not only ord.

Comment: Sorry.I am not updating the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is related to `time` (or `id`) this could work.

```
SET @order:=0;
UPDATE tbl_test
SET ord=@order:=@order+1
WHERE group=1
ORDER BY time, id
```

The answer above is borrowed from: [updating columns with a sequence number mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617056/updating-columns-with-a-sequence-number-mysql)

Alternative method found from: [Mysql Insert Order Number By VARCHAR Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702539/mysql-insert-order-number-by-varchar-field?lq=1)

```
SET @order:=0;
UPDATE 
SET ord=@order:=@order + 1
FROM tbl_test
ORDER BY time, id
```

Resetting `AUTO_INCREMENT` `id` might also be an option if no `ord` column is not in use.

Comment: No order is not related to time or id.

Comment: Thanks ZZ-bb i got the answer

SET @order:=0;
UPDATE tbl_test
SET ord=@order:=@order+1
WHERE group=1
ORDER BY ord;