# Import data in MySQL from a CSV file using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, csv, import, load-data-infile

I am importing some data of 20,000 rows from a CSV file into MySQL.

Columns in the CSV file are in a different order than MySQL tables' columns. How can I automatically assign columns corresponding to MySQL table columns?

When I execute

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc
```

this query adds all data to the first column.

What is the auto syntax for importing data to MySQL?

Comment: There is a similar topic in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077801/import-csv-to-mysql-table/32949959#32949959

Comment: It happened to me, I found out that the text file was written with lines terminated by '\r' and I was trying to import the data expecting the lines to be terminated using the '\n'

Comment: I wrote extensive tutorial to [load csv data into mysql](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/load-delimited-data-csv-excel-into-mysql-server) along with a [syntax generator tool in Excel](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-load-data-infile-syntax-generator-tool). It should be useful to readers.

Comment: Do *any* of the existing answers actually answer the question *"Columns in the CSV file are in a different order than MySQL tables' columns. How can I automatically assign columns corresponding to MySQL table columns?"*? They all instead *seem* to answer ***the more general question*** in the title of the question. Alternatively, is the question illogical or unclear?

Answer (score 224):

You can use the **LOAD DATA INFILE** command to import a CSV file into a table.

Check the link *[**MySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)*.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5...);
```

**For MySQL 8.0 users:**

Using the `LOCAL` keyword holds security risks and as of MySQL 8.0 the `LOCAL` capability is set to `False` by default. You might see the error:

> ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

You can overwrite it by following the [instructions in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html). Beware that such an overwrite does not solve the security issue, but rather is just an acknowledgment that you are aware and willing to take the risk.

Comment: May I know what ```IGNORE 1 LINES``` exactly does here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KoushikDas It will ignore the first line which defines column names

Comment: caution: the LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' clause works for windows files, but linux files should have '\n' only.

Comment: Important to remember to use forward slashes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42878067/470749

Comment: just a note that the (col1, col2, col3....) is not required. Useful if you are creating a table on the fly before using this to insert data.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill It's better to define LINES TERMINATOR when export data.

Comment: Adding to the caution note by @ChuckCottrill,  some Windows programs, such as WordPad, may use `\r` as a line terminator when writing files. To read such files, use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'.

Answer (score 64):

You probably need to set the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` or whatever the delimiter happens to be.

For a CSV file, your statement should look like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...Without LOCAL it was access denied.

Answer (score 57):

Before importing the file, you need to prepare the following:

- A database table to which the data from the file will be imported.
- A CSV file with data that matches with the number of columns of the
  table and the type of data in each column.
- The account, which connects to the MySQL database server, has FILE
  and INSERT privileges.

Suppose we have the following table:

[image]

Create the table using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `survey` (
  `projectId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `surveyId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `views` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `dateTime` datetime NOT NULL
);
```

Your CSV file must be properly formatted. For example, see the following attached image:

[image]

If everything is fine, please execute the following query to load data from the CSV file:

*Note*: Please add the absolute path of your CSV file

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/csv/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE survey 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

If everything has been done, you have exported data from the CSV file to the table successfully.

Comment: How can we validate if CSV file have proper datatype for each column because by default it ignores invalid datatype.

Answer (score 19):

Syntax:

```sql
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL]
INFILE 'file_name' INTO TABLE `tbl_name`
CHARACTER SET [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
FIELDS [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}[TERMINATED BY 'string']]
[LINES[TERMINATED BY 'string']]
[IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
```

See this example:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'E:\\wamp\\tmp\\customer.csv' INTO TABLE `customer`
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: On Windows, presumably? What version of MySQL was it tested with? What version of Windows?

Answer (score 13):

Insert bulk more than 7,000,000 records in 1 minute in the database (superfast query with calculation):

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
    INTO TABLE tablename
    FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (isbn10,isbn13,price,discount,free_stock,report,report_date)
     SET RRP = IF(discount = 0.00,price-price * 45/100,IF(discount = 0.01,price,IF(discount != 0.00,price-price * discount/100,@RRP))),
         RRP_nl = RRP * 1.44 + 8,
         ID = NULL
```

*RRP* and *RRP_bl* are not in the CSV file, but we are calculating those and insert them after that.

Comment: Calculations on the fly were not called for in the question.

Comment: we give extra , not wrong knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` from the Windows shell, and you need to use `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`, you will have to do something like this in order to escape characters properly:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql" -u root --password=%password% -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '!file!' INTO TABLE !table! FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"^""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES" --verbose --show-warnings > mysql_!fname!.out
```

Comment: What Windows shell? [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)? [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) (first introduced in 2006)?

Answer (score 2):

Let’s suppose you are using [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) and [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin).

You have file name 'ratings.txt' table name 'ratings' and database name 'movies'.

If your XAMPP is installed in "C:\xampp", copy your "ratings.txt" file in the "C:\xampp\mysql\data\movies" folder.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'ratings.txt' INTO TABLE ratings FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

This may work if you are doing this on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

By these days (ending 2019) I prefer to use a tool like *[Convert CSV to SQL](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm)*.

If you got a lot of rows, you can run partitioned blocks saving user mistakes when the CSV comes from a final user spreadsheet.

Comment: There's a CSV Lint plug-in for Notepad++ that can do the same thing  https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit **my.ini** file and add the following `secure-file-priv = ""` under `[mysqld]` section. Also if already any variable set for this then remove that.
2. Then restart the MySQL service and execute the following command to check whether the value has been successfully changed or not:

   `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`
3. Then you can execute the following query in the MySQL installed system and import the data,

   ```
   LOAD DATA INFILE "csv file location" INTO TABLE tablename
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   IGNORE 1 LINES
   (column1,column2,.....);
   ```

   > Note: (column name separated by comma as per csv file)
4. To add any CSV file from any other remote system you can also do the following after the above step:

   ```
   show global variables like 'local_infile';
   -- Note: if the value is OFF then execute the next command below
   set global local_infile=true; 
   -- check back again if the value has been set to ON or not
   ```
5. Execute the following command to import data from CSV file from any other system,

   ```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "csv file location" INTO TABLE tablename
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   IGNORE 1 LINES
   (column1,column2,.....);
   -- column name separated by comma as per csv file
   ```

Comment: It would be useful if you wrapped your code with the code tags.

Comment: Thanks @Jairus for the suggestion will further use the code tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can load data from a CSV or text file.

If you have a text file with records from a table, you can load those records within the table.

For example, if you have a text file, where each row is a record with the values for each column, you can load the records this way.

#### File *table.sql*

```
id //field 1

name //field2
```

#### File *table.txt*

```
1,peter

2,daniel

...
```

#### Example on Windows

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\directory_example\\table.txt'
INTO TABLE Table
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Yes, but the question was about CSV - *"Import data in MySQL from a CSV file using LOAD DATA INFILE"*

Answer (score 1):

You can try to insert like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/filename.csv' replace INTO TABLE [table name] FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (field1,field2,field3);
```

Comment: The last part, "(field1,field2,field3)", is different from most of the other answers. An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53476068/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting

> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

This worked for me on [Windows 8.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1) 64 bit using [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) Server 3.0.6 64 bit:

- I edited my.ini file from *C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14*.
- Delete entry secure_file_priv c:\wamp64\tmp\ (or whatever directory you have here).
- I stopped everything—with *exit wamp*, etc.—and restarted everything; then put my CVS file on *C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\data\u242349266_recur* (the last directory being my database name)
- I executed

  ```
   LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv'

   INTO TABLE alumnos

   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

   ENCLOSED BY '"'

   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

   IGNORE 1 LINES
  ```
- ... and voilà!!!

Answer (score 0):

create A table in Mysql

```sql
CREATE TABLE Address_Book (  
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    NAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,   
    Email VARCHAR(35),  
    Mobile INT(12),   
    Address VARCHAR(45)  
);
```

than create a csv file at location `D:\\csvfiles\\address.csv`

paste the below content into the csv file

```
ID, Name, Email, Mobile, Address

"1","Tushar Bhadwaj","jorge@abc.com","4848488","123 Park Street"

"2","Peter","peter@gma.com","4848485","321 Fake Avenue"

"3","Michael Clark","clark@rt.com","4848487","321 Park Avenue"

"4","James Franklin","james@lk.com","4848489","321 Fake Avenue"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkU0P.png)

And than execute the below command for import the csv file content---

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\csvfiles\\address.csv' 
INTO TABLE Address_Book 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

All the detail already provided in the page .In case you can't understand
you can click on below link .The content is same as on page.

https://youtu.be/Gp7XYM_Hr3c

Comment: When promoting your own content (i.e. your youtube link) you need to make it's clear that it's yours. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: All the detail already defined on the page 
if he/she can't understand then they can go for link

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc fields terminated by '|' (@filecol1,@filecol2,@filecol3)
SET filecol =@filecol1, filecol2 =@filecol2, filecol3 =@filecol3
```

Here you would require to check your CSV how the fields are being terminated I worked on certain files. The Files may use  , | ; \t etc

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

To add more context to the accepted answer, I would like to give an example.

Here’s a sample CSV:

[image]

Your MySQL configuration may dictate the success (or failure) of the LOAD INFILE. With mine, loading is disabled for both the client and server. So, initially, I get this error:

Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides.

So, you might need to check the [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) server variable and set this in the client:

```html
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;
```

The location of the CSV file also matters depending on your client. Since I use dbForge Studio for MySQL, it looks for the path on where dbForge is installed (C:\Program Files\Devart\dbForge Edge\dbForge Studio for MySQL). Or, if there’s a path in secure_file_priv, put it there.

Once the requirements are in place, the LOAD INFILE should work. However, you may need to adjust based on runtime errors thrown to you.

Below shows the target table and the exact LOAD INFILE syntax I used:

[image]

Note that the customer table has more columns than the CSV file. That’s why at the end of the LOAD INFILE, the customer_name, email, and address columns are explicitly specified. The column names are based on the target table but the arrangement is based on the columns from the CSV file (See above images).

In the end, I got this:

[image]

After using LOAD INFILE, I used a simple SELECT to the customer table to see if the 10 rows are there.

Using LOAD INFILE is fine to import a CSV to MySQL. But dealing with syntax errors may be annoying. So, using a GUI is my preferred method. Of course, it’s not without problems too but connecting, loading, and column mappings, are easier understood. I used [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver16) and [Skyvia](https://skyvia.com/connectors/mysql) for some time. Others may have different preferences but I have experience on these so I mentioned them here.

I hope it helps.