# Symfony - How to load initial data to database

Tags: mysql, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.7 and Mysql
I need to load some real data to database like needed data for countries and cities tables and their relations. What is the right way to do such tasks in Symfony?

Comment: no different than PHP I imagine. Don't use PHP loops, use mysql LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Import CSV file to mysql database Using LOAD DATA INFILE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915104/php-import-csv-file-to-mysql-database-using-load-data-infile)

Comment: I would suggest you use [Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

Comment: @TurdalievNursultan I'd use fixtures in dev environment for testing

Comment: @Drew (Updated the question) What about the relation between them?

Comment: That would be represented in the schema and the CSV upload. 1 CSV file per table

Answer (score 4):

For generating test data, use [data fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html). For generating data required in productions, I suggest to use [migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html).