# How to upload a large csv file with 500k+ rows to my database scheduled everyday

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

Here's my problem:

I get a large **csv file with 500k+ rows** stored on to my server everyday.

I can access these files through filezilla.  What I want to do is to use php to get the latest csv file every day and upload it to my database.

I have tried looping through the rows to add them to the database one by one but that was to no avail. I read online and found that ***LOAD INFILE*** might be what i am looking for but I don't know how to implement that to load files that are stored on my server.

Also, I don't know how to **automate** that upload so it runs **every day**. 
Thank you

Comment: What issues were you experiencing when you processed the CSV one line at a time? Are the contents of the CSV file actually CSV rows or are they DB `insert` statements?

Comment: You said, :I have tried looping through the rows to add them to the database one by one but that was to no avail".  How did you do that?  What was the problem that prevented it from working?  500k+ is not that large in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: when loop through the file line by line, it only inserts about 50k of the rows. Its not inserting all the rows in my csv files. @MonkeyZeus The contents of the CSV are actual CSV rows not insert statements.

Comment: Does it produce an error after 50k rows? If yes then what error?

Comment: I figured out a way to Insert all the rows in the CSV by looping through the file and using PHP's fgetcsv() function. Now I want to be able to automate this so it can insert to my database every day. Do you have any idea on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score -1):

- You can check **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915104/php-import-csv-file-to-mysql-database-using-load-data-infile)** to the same problem that you
  have.
- And for the other issue about the scheduled task, you could check **[tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)** about the timer functions in ***Javascript***

I hope these tips will help you

```html
<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert('Hello');
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does Javascript has to do with this question?

Comment: @RaymondNijland This is blatant spam and/or upvote mongering. It has nothing to do with anything and should be downvoted into oblivion.