# Inserting several thousand entries into MySQL with one query

Tags: mysql, arrays, bulkinsert

I'm trying to store around 6,000 post codes into my database but of course I don't want to individually insert them.

I have a text file containing the post codes I need for the task

The text file looks like this,

```
SS99 6LB,SS8 9RA,SS7 9SR,SS7 9SS,SS7 9ST
```

I'd like to insert them all into the database in one hit.

The table structure is simply ID(INT), Postcode(VAR).

Comment: Consider using LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: Have you tried to Import them in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Sure, but I'm not that great when it comes to the knowhow.. I'm more of a designer these days but I need to develop something simple. 

How and where would I successfully import the values in phpMyAdmin from the txt file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/mysql-import-data-from-csv-using-load-data-infile

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' 
INTO TABLE tablename
LINES TERMINATED BY ','
(Postcode) 
;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

first of all assign this text from the text file to a string

```
$string ='that text';
$arr = explode(",",$string);
```

thats an idea/concept you can now make a loop

```
$sql="";
foreach($arr as $ar)
{
 //$sql.=($sql=="")?"":",";
 //$sql.=$ar;
  mysql_query("insert into table(Postcodes) values ($ar)");
}
```

check syntax of quotes around postecodes according to your server

for performance you can write it will insert all in one query

```
$sql="insert into table(Postcodes) values";
foreach($arr as $ar)
{
 $sql.=($sql=="insert into table(Postcodes) values")?"":",";

  $sql.="(".$ar.")";
}
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: that will run 6000 queries... you can do much better than that.

Comment: basically he wants to insert it, he has not said that he wants performance, mysql can run taht much

Comment: yeah, but it's dumb to do it that way when you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE`, or even concatenate all the values into a single string and send it to the DB in a single query. To make things worse, your example uses the deprecated mysql extension.

Comment: this can be right if question was about "with best approcah" or "with better performance" i just showed him a way to do it with php as its "php" question :)