# Load Data Infile - Not working from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written a script to import CSV files into a mySQL database. However when I try to run the SQL from a PHP script it doesn't work. It does work when I put the SQL query into phpMyAdmin.

```
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password123';
$database = 'product';

$connect = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

if($connect->connect_error) {
    die('Connection Failed' . $connection->connect_error);
}

$files = scandir('imports/');

foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $import =
            "LOAD DATA INFILE 'imports/$file'
            IGNORE INTO TABLE temp_import
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (@deal_id, @redeemed_at, @wowcher_code, @deal_title, @customer_name, @house_name_number, @address_line_1, @address_line_2,
        @city, @county, @postcode, @email, @phone, @date_of_birth, @custom_field, @marketing_permission, @product_name, @product_options)
        set deal_id=@deal_id, redeemed_at=@redeemed_at, wowcher_code=@wowcher_code, deal_title=@deal_title, customer_name=@customer_name,
        house_name_number=@house_name_number, address_line_1=@address_line_1, address_line_2=@address_line_2, city=@city, county=@county,
        postcode=@postcode, email=@email, phone=@phone, date_of_birth=@date_of_birth, custom_field=@custom_field,
        marketing_permission=@marketing_permission, product_name=@product_name, product_options=@product_options";

        if(! $connect->query($import)) {
            echo 'Failed: ' . $file . PHP_EOL;
        }

        else {
            $connect->query($import);

            echo mysqli_affected_rows($connect) . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see why this may not be working

Comment: `'imports/$file'` is a relative path! Make it a absolute path!

Comment: And check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/mysql-import-data-from-csv-using-load-data-infile

Comment: Thank you! It would have to be the most simple thing. I don't really understand why that fixes it though. with the relative path it still founds the files in the directory

Comment: What does _"doesn't work"_ mean? Error messages? Blanks screen? Computer catches on fire?

Comment: Relative paths are not always relative from that files location. If you include this file from another file, located in another folder, it will be relative from that files location.

Comment: @Edward144 That comes first in mind. Because i dont thing PHP is telling MYSQL about the current working directory. Check the Link, there are good examples...