# Import Excel sheet data in to Mysql using Web application

Tags: mysql, excel, jakarta-ee

I need to upload data in an excel sheet to the database using java.

The database will be oracle.

The excel sheet will be uploaded once in a month by a user using a web application (Servlets and JSP).

The excel sheet will be having thousands of records/rows e.g. around 15000 or more.

What is the fastest way to upload this huge data in database? We are using simple JDBC (Spring's JDBC Template).
How do we handle transaction sand errors as there can be errors while uploading data in which case the partly uploaded data will be useless?
We need to able to notify the user of the error so that he can correct the excel sheet and try again?
Please help/

Comment: You may find your solution here at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14133423/1578380

Comment: could you please provide some further clearity, how can i use it in my web application.I would be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

To import excel sheet data into mysql, first convert it to csv and then use following code to import it in database

Login to mysql

```
mysql -u root -p
<type password>
```

Import data to table using this query

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

here the data.csv file must be located at valid path specified by mysql default configuration, typically you have to save this `data.csv` at `/var/tmp/` path. If you wish to specify custom path where file is located e.g. `/home/ubuntu/data.csv` then make sure that `secure-file-priv` is disabled.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer sir. But  i do not directly want to upload the excel to the database.I have a web application and through that web application i want to upload the data of excel into the database.

Comment: You have to run LOAD DATA .... query in any server side scripting language, e.g. PHP