# Load directory of .txt.gz files into MySQL

Tags: mysql

I try to load an SQL dump into a MySQL database.

The dump contains a `.sql` file which creates all tables in the database. Along with the `.sql` file, there are tab separated `.txt.gz` files with the data for the tables. The file name matches the table name and the file contains no headers.

- `database.sql`
- `table1.txt.gz`
- `table2.txt.gz`
- `table3.txt.gz`
- ...

**Question:** Was this created with a standard dump tool? Is this a standard database dump format? Can load this with e.g. `mysql`, `mysqldump` or something similar?

I know of course that I can iterate the files and load them one by one.

The data comes from: ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/grch37/release-94/mysql/homo_sapiens_core_94_37/

Comment: This can be done "manually" in Mysql Workbench. When you `SELECT *` you can export the result in many differents format. Text/CSV has only datas (fields names too)

Comment: This looks like the output of `select * from tablename into outfile 'filename'` (if it came from mysql - the source might be something else, which could explain why it's not a normal mysqldump). The in-mysql reverse operation is [`load data infile`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14127529/6248528), but there are also numerous other tools that allow you to import csv files. If the filenames match the tablenames and the column order, you can probably create a simple batch for this and loop through all files, but maybe one of the files in that folder contains a script to import the data that way.