# Optimizing/improving data insert with Zend_Db_Table

Tags: php, zend-framework, optimization, insertion

On my ZF project, I'm importing data from a CSV file and after some treatement, I insert the data in my MySQL database with a Zend_Db_Table. Here's what the code looks like:

```
private function addPerson($data)
{
    $personDao = new Person();
    $personRow = $personDao ->createRow();

    if($newperson == -1) 
    {
        //already in DB
    }
    else
    {
        $personRow->setName($data['name']);
        ...
        $personRow->save();
    }
}
```

It's working just fine. My only concern is the time it'll take for thousands of rows to be inserted using this way.
So my question is: Is there anyway I can improve my code for large files?
Can I still use the save() function for a lot of rows (>6000) ?
Any suggestion will be welcome.

I was wondering if there's a ZEND function that can buffer like 500 rows and insert them in one shot instead of using save() on each row. I'm already at 1min for 6000 rows...

Comment: Your $newperson is not initialized anywhere

Comment: Yeah it's a return value of a function I call that fetch the table to see if the id is in there. Sorry, didn't put the whole code, but as said, it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think to optimize the integration of csv file, you must transfer the work to MySQL. Either stored or through PHP command line procedure.
It will be create a new file for your tables.
You will find ideas in [Import CSV to mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077801/import-csv-to-mysql-table).

I did not do, but I think it is quite feasible.

I hope it will help you :)