# Get data from CSV file and storing the it in a database (Visual basic)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, csv

My goal is to create a little program that gets data from 10 different CSV. files and storing the infomation in a mysql database. Each CSV file should be linked to it's own table. 10 CSV files and 10 tables in the database.

I am doing this in Visual studio with VB6

What is the best way to this? 
How do i handle the data from each file and input them in the right cells in the database?

Do i need 10 different filereaders and 10 different SQL queries to do this?
When should I open and close the connection to the database?

Comment: Are you sure you are using VB6 (aka VB98 as in 1998)?

Comment: probably not. thought that was the name of the latest...

Comment: in VS, open Help menu, click About

Comment: "Visual Basic" 2013 is completely unrelated to Visual Basic at all, and certainly not to VB6.  You are a victim of an ill conceived marketing strategy that attempts to conflate two entirely different programming language families.  In any case this is a MySQL question, so look up its CSV import SQL syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import CSV to mysql table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077801/import-csv-to-mysql-table)