# Grab all descriptions on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql, automation

On this web page: http://www.wpc-edi.com/reference/codelists/healthcare/remittance-advice-remark-codes/

I want to grab every title and Description and turn them into an insert statement. So for the first 3:

They are

- M1 | X-ray not taken within the past 12 months or near enough to the
  start of treatment.
- M2 | Not paid separately when the patient is an inpatient.
- M3 | Equipment is the same or similar to equipment already being used.

and turn these into

```
  INSERT INTO CODE(CODE, DESCRIPTION, TYPE_CODE) VALUES ("M1", "X-ray not taken within the past 12 months or near enough to the
       start of treatment.", SELECT ID from CODE where CODE_KEY = "RARC");
  INSERT INTO CODE(CODE, DESCRIPTION, TYPE_CODE) VALUES ("M2", "Not paid separately when the patient is an inpatient.", SELECT ID from CODE where CODE_KEY = "RARC");
  INSERT INTO CODE(CODE, DESCRIPTION, TYPE_CODE) VALUES ("M3", " Equipment is the same or similar to equipment already being used.", SELECT ID from CODE where CODE_KEY = "RARC");
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Maybe in Javascript? Because right now I am just copy-pasting these values into my insert statements.

Comment: You might want to use a csv file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077801/import-csv-to-mysql-table

Comment: How could I get this all into a CSV file though?

Comment: Copy, paste into excel?