# Adding primary key to existing MySQL table in alembic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am trying to add an 'id' primary key column to an already existing MySQL table using alembic. I tried the following...

```
op.add_column('mytable', sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
op.alter_column('mytable', 'id', autoincrement=True, existing_type=sa.Integer(), existing_server_default=False, existing_nullable=False)
```

but got the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1075, 'Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key') 'ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE id id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' ()
```

looks like the sql statement generated by alembic did not add `PRIMARY KEY` at the end of the alter statement. Could I have missed some settings?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I spent some time digging through the alembic source code, and this doesn't seem to be supported.  You can specify primary keys when *creating* a table, but not when adding columns. In fact, it specifically checks and won't let you ([link to source](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/blob/ec8db7d875f486cde2d02942bd8409abf37e3704/alembic/operations/toimpl.py#L134-L136)):

```
# from alembic.operations.toimpl.add_column, line 132
for constraint in t.constraints:
    if not isinstance(constraint, sa_schema.PrimaryKeyConstraint):
        operations.impl.add_constraint(constraint)
```

I looked around, and adding a primary key to an existing table may result in unspecified behavior - primary keys aren't supposed to be null, so your engine may or may not create primary keys for existing rows. See this SO discussion for more info:  [Insert auto increment primary key to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764/insert-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-database)

I'd just run the alter query directly, and create primary keys if you need to.

```
op.execute("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;")
```

If you really need cross-engine compatibility, the big hammer would be to (1) create a new table identical to the old one with a primary key, (2) migrate all your data, (3)delete the old table and (4) rename the new table.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the primary key that is in the table and then create a new one that includes all columns that you want as the primary key.

eg. In psql use `\d <table name>` to define the schema, then check the primary key constraint.

```
Indexes:
"enrollments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (se_crs_id, se_std_id)
```

then use this information in alembic

```
def upgrade():
# ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
op.add_column('enrollments', sa.Column(
    'se_semester', sa.String(length=30), nullable=False))
op.drop_constraint('enrollments_pkey', 'enrollments', type_='primary')
op.create_primary_key('enrollments_pkey', 'enrollments', [
                      'se_std_id', 'se_crs_id', 'se_semester'])
```

The results after running `\d enrollments` should be updated to

```
Indexes:
"enrollments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (se_std_id, se_crs_id, se_semester)
```

This solution worked fine for me.

Comment: The question is about MySQL, so an answer using psql isn't very useful.