# Alter Primary Key in Alembic?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I've read through [the docs](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html), but I can't find instructions on this anywhere. I tried dropping the old key and adding a new one, but that gets me errors:

```
op.drop_constraint('PRIMARY', 'some_table', type_='primary')
op.create_primary_key('PRIMARY', 'some_table', ['col1', 'col2'])

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1025, "Error on rename of ... (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)") 'ALTER TABLE some_table DROP PRIMARY KEY ' ()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not quite the same thing, but this might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756567/adding-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-table-in-alembic/13757758#13757758

Comment: @RachelSanders I found that while searching for answers. Was hoping something's improved since 2012 though. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Eli It would be very useful the next time you find the answer to your own question if you were to post it below. On a quick google search for "alembic alter primary key" this post is the first result. I don't want to come across as a jerk but a question with an update from the original poster with "I found the answer" and no more details really does nothing for the community :-/.

Comment: @Frito you misread my comments. I don't have a better answer than RachelSanders'. I'm still hoping a better method is added to Alembic in the future, but currently I have no better answer to post.

Comment: @Eli Ha! You're indeed correct. I did misread your comment. My apologies. For anyone else reading the comments I ended up having an issue where the above error (150) was due to a FK constraint referencing the PK of the table I was trying to update. I ended up removing that constraint, updating my PK then re-adding the constraint.

Comment: Update for 2023, as far as I can tell, alembic still hasn't added detection for primary key changes. So manually removing constraint is still the way to go. (I'd be happy to be proven wrong though)

Answer (score 35):

I also was in the same situation: alter primary key. In my case, I had to change the primary key type from integer to string.

The primary key also had a foreign key relationship to another table. The earlier alembic migration created the foreign key constraint in the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    op.create_table('user',
                    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=100), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('username', sa.String(length=100), nullable=False),
                    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name=op.f('pk_user')),
                    sa.UniqueConstraint('username', name=op.f('uq_user_username'))
                    )

    op.create_table('role',
                    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
                    sa.Column('name', sa.String(100)),
                    sa.Column('description', sa.String(255)),
                    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name=op.f('pk_role'))
                    )

    op.create_table('roles_users',
                    sa.Column('user_id', sa.Integer, nullable=True),
                    sa.Column('role_id', sa.Integer, nullable=True),
                    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['user_id'], ['user.id'],
                                            name=op.f('fk_roles_user_user_id_user')),
                    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['role_id'], ['role.id'],
                                            name=op.f('fk_roles_user_role_id_role'))
                    )
```

Now when changing the primary key type of the `user` table from `Integer` to `String`, I had to do the following:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    # Drop primary key constraint. Note the CASCASE clause - this deletes the foreign key constraint.
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE user DROP CONSTRAINT pk_user CASCADE')
    # Change primary key type
    op.alter_column('user', 'id', existing_type=sa.Integer, type_=sa.VARCHAR(length=25))
    op.alter_column('roles_users', 'user_id', existing_type=sa.Integer, type_=sa.VARCHAR(length=25))
    # Re-create the primary key constraint
    op.create_primary_key('pk_user', 'user', ['id'])
    # Re-create the foreign key constraint
    op.create_foreign_key('fk_roles_user_user_id_user', 'roles_users', 'user', ['user_id'], ['id'], ondelete='CASCADE')
```

Flask version: `0.12.1`

Alembic version: `0.9.1`

Python version: `3.4.4`

Hope this information helps someone facing a similar problem.

Comment: +1 This answer not only tells how to alter a primary key, but also how to do it when this primary key has a foreign key relationship with another table.

Comment: In my Postgres DB the PK constraints created by Alembic / SA are named using the `user_pkey` pattern instead of `pk_user`

Answer (score 19):

I came across this question looking for a sample migration. So here is my full migration that drops the PK constraint and adds a new `AUTO INCREMENT` PK instead:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER


def upgrade():
    op.drop_constraint('PRIMARY', 'similar_orders', type_='primary')

    op.execute("ALTER TABLE similar_orders ADD COLUMN id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT")


def downgrade():
    op.drop_column('similar_orders', 'id')

    op.create_primary_key("similar_orders_pk", "similar_orders", ["order_id", ])
```

Altering PK on column does not work in alembic, use drop_constraint instead, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756567/adding-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-table-in-alembic). Hope this helps!

Comment: This was the solution for me (adding a new column to the composite primary key). The constraint — autogenerated by SQLAlchemy — was named `<table_name>_pkey` in my case.

Comment: Instead of the raw SQL `execute`, you could probably do something along these lines to stay with native alembic and SQLAlchemy: `op.add_column('similar_orders', sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True))`

Answer (score 0):

I am using sql script with (postgres sql):

```
def upgrade() -> None:
    op.execute("ALTER TABLE some_table ADD CONSTRAINT some_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2);")

def downgrade() -> None:
    op.execute("ALTER TABLE some_table DROP CONSTRAINT some_table_pkey;")
```