# Migrating Primary Key to use AUTO_Increment

Tags: mysql

I have a table where the primary key is sale_id, payment_type

```
mysql> describe phppos_sales_payments;
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sale_id        | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| payment_type   | varchar(255)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| payment_amount | decimal(15,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to add a new field `id` that is an auto increment. The reason for this is I want to track payments of the same type individually. Is it possible to do this without losing data?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764/insert-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can alter your table

```
ALTER TABLE `phppos_sales_payments`
  -- add a unique index based on the current primary key
  ADD UNIQUE (`sale_id`,`payment_type`), 
  -- drop the current primary key
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
  -- add the new identity column with autoincrement
  ADD COLUMN `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
  -- set primary key to the new identity column 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

The "magic" is to add an unique index, because foreign key must have an index and in second place add the new identity column with autoincrement and set the primary key for that column in one go.

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/907d0/1)

Comment: What does FIRST mean in the AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: @ChrisMuench the new column will be in first place of your table columns. Normal would be at the last. It's just to have the PK Column on top -> cosmetic :o)

Answer (score 1):

Just keep your sale_id, payment_type key, but not as primary, then add an `id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and make that the primary key: no loss of information and new primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to execute a single ALTER TABLE statement to achieve this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
ADD COLUMN id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST, 
ADD UNIQUE sale_id_payment_type( sale_id, payment_type );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ALTER TABLE `table` DROP PRIMARY KEY,  

 ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
 ALTER TABLE `table` ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: I tried to drop the primary key, but I got #1025 - Error on rename of './pos/#sql-299_17' to './pos/phppos_sales_payments' (errno: 150) 

This is because sale_id is a foreign key referencing another table (FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_sales` (`sale_id`)).

Is there a way around this?