# This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available

Tags: phpmyadmin

The error generated in phpMyAdmin is:

> This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

What does this error message mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure your table names are LOWER CASE... if they are upper case, it will cause this error.

Comment: I Agree with nonybrighto here, before you radically over think things and start adding primary keys and what not check your table names first, make sure they are all lower case. It worked for me and has worked several times in the past. Recent versions of PHPMyAdmin seem to be more affected than older ones.

Comment: Another add in to this, if you have imported any data and run into issues with compatibility for whatever reason and your import was interrupted. You may have missed some of the table alter queries at the bottom of your SQL import file. Check there and see if the assignments you are looking for are in your file to import before mass assignments of primary keys and so forth are tried. This is a wonderful solution, to the RIGHT problem. Always be careful when importing large quantities of data. Check and re-check.

Answer (score 61):

I have been faced with this problem.
The cause is your table **doesn't have a primary key field**.
And I have a simple solution: Set a field to primary key to specific field that suits your business logic.
For example, I have database `thesis_db` and field `thesis_id`, I will press button Primary (key icon) to set `thesis_id` to become primary key field:
[image]

Comment: It could be a solution if the table contains a key to be primary. It's not obvious as if you have a connecter table with just foreign keys, they can't be primary and/or unique. phpMyAdmin makes updates where clause based on a primary key, however you can add multiple options and execute it manually.

Comment: @gramgram, your comment is helpful. We also add 2 or more than foreign keys. We also use SQL statement to set primary key or foreign keys combination.

Comment: For a table that doesn't have a unique field, this was helpful for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764/insert-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-database

Comment: In my case , using the auto increment id as the primary key DID notwork. I had to use Passport Number as the Primary Key. The warning disappearred after that.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me. A silly error but I'm very new to SQL. :D

Answer (score 24):

This is not an error. PhpMyAdmin is just informing you, that there is no unique ID column in your result set. Depending on the type of query you sent, this is the desired behaviour.

It is not MySQL which is saying it needs a unique ID, if any combination of the columns in your result set is unique, the values of those columns can be used in an UPDATE or DELETE query. It is phpMyAdmin which says it does not have enough information to offer you the checkboxes and buttons you will normally see in a result set with unique ID.

Comment: how do i create a unique id?  i've got a search query that returns a unique result, but i still can't edit like i sued to be able to.

Comment: Your result might be unique, but the columns in the result are not. Let's say you've got 2 columns A and B, where A is unique and B is not, and you go: SELECT `B` FROM `table` WHERE `A`='some value, then your result is only returned from column B, which is not unique. From there PhpMyAdmin can not give you the edit options because you can't distinguish one line from the other in your result.

Comment: The above code doesn't show correctly. Couldn't find out how to get backticks because codes are marked with it as well. Sorry.

Comment: Solution is very easy, just make a field `primary` which has unique values and all the problems will be solved automatically.

Answer (score 18):

Simply create a new column, set the `Name` to whatever you like, set the `Type` to `INT` and **check the box that says `A_I`**.

[image: diagram]
The `A_I` checkbox stands for `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which essentially means that sequence numbers are assigned automatically in that new column (see below).

```
 column1 | column2 | id
-----------------------
 value   | value   | 1
-----------------------
 value   | value   | 2
-----------------------
 value   | value   | 3
-----------------------
 value   | value   | 4
```

This column essentially acts as a reference for phpMyAdmin to delete rows from. If necessary, click on the unique button for this new column, although this happened automatically for me. After following the above steps, you should no longer have the error message and buttons should appear for editing rows in phpMyAdmin!

Comment: Good answer, it help me

Comment: This helps me too. Should be mark as correct answer :)

Comment: I get "#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Answer (score 13):

My case is different.  This issue is only specific to PHPMyAdmin. I downloaded couple other admin tools (Adminer, MySQLWorkbench, HeidiSQL etc) and the same db works fine in all of those.

I have all the indexes, primary key and unique keys defined and still get the error. I get this after I upgraded to MySQL 5.6 (did not face the same with the previous versions).

Turns out PMA has issues with Table names in capital.  PMA is not able to recognise keys with capital table names. Once I change them to small (`ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=INNODB` -- I use INNODB -- does that for each table without changing anything else), I was able to access normally. I'm on a Windows system with UniformServer.

Comment: I have the same problem. I cannot change the table Names. Is there another way to correct this?

Comment: Try using one of the other options like HeidiSQL.

Comment: I changed the names in WAMP but not on Linux Host! Everything works now without changing code. The names are upper case on my code.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you get rid of that notice and be able to open those grid cells for edit

1) click "STRUCTURE"

2) go to the field you want to be a primary key (and this usually is the 1st one ) and then click on the "PRIMARY" and "INDEX" fields for that field and accept the PHPMyadmin's pop-up question "OK".

3) pad yourself in the back.

Comment: Perfect answer that doesn't involve risky configuration changes.

Answer (score 3):

An easy fix to this would be going to the SQL tab and just simply put in the code

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Asuming that you have a row named id.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this in the `config.inc.php` file worked for me (under the last $cfg line):

`$cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique'] = 'true';`

The file should be located in the `phpMyAdmin` folder on your local computer

Comment: This is a very risky option. In case there is really no unique row, an UPDATE or DELETE could easily affect the entire table.

Answer (score 2):

I have been faced this problem.

The cause is your table don't have a primary key field.

And I have a simple solution: Set a field to primary key to specific filed that suit with your business logic.
For example, I have database thesis_db and field thesis_id, I will press button Primary (key icon) to set thesis_id to become primary key field

Answer (score 1):

I recently got the same problem and after looking for duplicates I was able to fix it just by setting (missing) primary key on the table. Hope this could help

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error occured in phpmyadmin version 4.5.1 when i set lower_case_table_names = 2 and had a table name with uppercase characters, The table had a primary key set to auto increment but still showed the error. The issue stopped when i changed the table name to all lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem whenever i am firing SELECT query with specific columns, though the one of the column is primary in table. I was trying to fetch selective records with selective columns in standard wordpress "posts" table. ID column is already primary and unique..

> Just specifying primary/unique column name will not resolve this issue. You have to specify full column name like "posts.id" (tablename.columnname) that tells PMA to select specific column and reveals edit etc..

My PMA is 4.3.8. Let me know if this helps..

Answer (score 1):

the code that worked for me

```
ALTER TABLE `table name`
ADD COLUMN `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Answer (score 1):

This for sure is an old topic but I want to add up to the voices to crop maybe new ideas.
To address the WARNING issue under discussions, all you need to do is to set one of your table columns to a PRIMARY KEY constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This question helped me identify the problem of why phpMyAdmin refused me grid-edit-etc. on some tables. I just had forgotten to declare my primary key and was overseeing it in my  *"Why the hell should this table be different from its neighbours"* solution search process...

I just wanted to react on following in OP self-answer:

> The other table had multiple AI int values that were the Primary
>   field, but there were multiple values of the same kind.
>
> The simple fix for this was to just add a column to the end of the
>   table as Unique AI Int. Basically all MySQL is saying is it needs a
>   unique value in each record to differentiate the rows.

This was actually my case, but there's absolutely no need to add any column: if your primary key is the combination of 2 fields (ex. junction table in many to many relationship), then simply declare it as such:
- eiter in phpyAdmin, just enter "2" in "Create an index on [x] columns", then select your 2 columns
- or `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY(mycol1,mycol2)`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to modify directly after running Query. Turns out, after making a view from that exact same query, I was able to modify the values.

Answer (score 0):

This for me was resolved by re-exporting the data from original source DB and then importing it into the mirror DB.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your tables have one primary key. I forgot to add a primary key to one table and that solved this problem for me. :)