# Merge column from two tables then connect with another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get emails in result. First need to get users id from two tables and connect it with users table to get email by id. In result I need only unique emails.

Im trying to construct something like this, but don't think it's right

```
SELECT distinct 'uid','login.email' 
FROM 'operations' 
left join 'login' on operations.uid=login.id 
UNION
SELECT distinct  'uid','login.email' 
FROM 'operations24' 
left join 'login' on operations.uid=login.id
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT distinct 'ops.uid','login.email' 
FROM (
    SELECT distinct 'uid'
    FROM 'operations' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT distinct 'uid'
    FROM 'operations24'
) as ops
left join 'login' 
        on ops.uid=login.id
```

You can use `UNION ALL` if the uid's in both tables were totally different
If there is any duplicate possible between both selects, better use just `UNION`
this will be slower.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I got: Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available. In result:
ops.uid  login.email  
ops.uid  login.email

Comment: Can you try it again, there was an error in the SELECT passage.

Comment: Im trying this:
SELECT distinct 'ops.uid','login.email' FROM ( SELECT distinct 'uid' FROM operations UNION ALL SELECT distinct 'uid' FROM operations24) as ops left join login on ops.uid=login.id but in result the same -  Current selection does not contain a unique column.

Comment: This is just a warning. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922503/resolution-this-table-does-not-contain-a-unique-column-grid-edit-checkbox-ed