# Getting count of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

If I run the query in `phpMyAdmin`:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ResultTable;

I get the warning (5.5.45 - MySQL Community Server):

> This table does not contain unique column. Changing the grid of the
>   show, editing, copying, and deleting is not available.

Then I make an existing field `result_id` as `Unique`:

> ALTER TABLE ResultTable ADD UNIQUE (result_id);

Nevertheless I get the same warning after `select` query, so where the trouble lies?

Comment: It might help to re-login into phpMyAdmin

Comment: @AlexShesterov Re-login does not make changes.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922503/resolution-this-table-does-not-contain-a-unique-column-grid-edit-checkbox-ed

Comment: @MustafaShujaie that completely explains the issue