# How to fix: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed wordpress on localhost with xampp,now I export MySQL database and import on my server,and when I try to edit wp-option, it says:

> This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

I'm not good in SQL so please help me not technically,easy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922503/how-to-fix-this-table-does-not-contain-a-unique-column-grid-edit-checkbox-ed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tables need a 'unique' column which is how you will identify each row.

Edit your table and make sure one of your columns are unique. You could create a new column called 'id' and make it 'unique' and 'auto-increment'.