# phpMyAdmin does not recognize primary key

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to link a foregin key to a primary key of a different table. In order to do that with the gui I have to click on "Propose table structure". But then I get this error:

```
 Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
```

I don't understand it, because I have an unique primary key.
However, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520180/mysql-current-selection-does-not-contain-a-unique-column-grid-edit-checkbox) the following line will supress the error but doesn't explain, why the primary key isn't recognized.

```
$cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique'] = true
```

This is my table

[image: Screenshot phpmyadmin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply go to `Structure` tab, then `Relation View` tab and add or edit `Foreign Key`.