# "Current selection does not contain a unique column" - can't edit in grid box

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to join two tables to edit some data in phpymadmin, but I get an error saying "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Both tables contain a primaray id and also a unique key. How can I solve this?

Tried the following code:

```
SELECT fights.game_id, f1.lastname, f2.lastname, f1.id, f2.id, wfighter, lfighter, e.date, e.organization, e.event, fights.event_id FROM `fights`
join fighters f1 ON
f1.id = fights.wfighter
join fighters f2 ON
f2.id = fights.lfighter
join event e ON
e.event_id = fights.event_id
where e.organization = '1'
order by e.date desc, fights.game_id desc
```

[image: https://ibb.co/7R6cJ5J]
[image: https://ibb.co/44PJHjk]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520180/mysql-current-selection-does-not-contain-a-unique-column-grid-edit-checkbox)

Comment: I can't see `organization` column from request in screenshots

Comment: Ancaron: Unfortunately I can't edit the config file of the phpmyadmin. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: kbo: The event table consist of id (int11, primary key), organization (varchar 45), date (datetime) and event (varchar 45).

Comment: maybe somewhat related to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15346