# phpMyAdmin get "Current selection does not contain a unique column." message when adding relationship

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am new to here and also new to MySQL/phpMyAdmin, so let me know any mistakes.

I tried to construct relationship between two tables by clicking "Propose table structure" button in Structure tab. However I cannot get into table structure setting at all. If the table do not have any data in it, I just sent to Browse tab. If the table has some data in it, I am also sent to Browse tab with message below.

> Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit,
>   checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
>   Documentation

I checked through SO and other sites for the error message and tried each solutions. However I cannot resolve this problem. Is there some missing settings to allow me to have relationship between tables or do I missing any procedure?

[Resolution: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922503/resolution-this-table-does-not-contain-a-unique-column-grid-edit-checkbox-ed)

I went through this thread and tried the solution. Each table have unique columns with A.I and Index and primary are set however it still shows me the message.

Also I saw other site suggesting problem with lower/upper latter column name, however it also didn't help me.

My environment is phpMyAdmin version 4.7.9 on Wampserver.

Let me know how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? How did you resolve this error?