# what is the correct way to select the highest value from column not primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have a table (report) consist of several records and one of them about int values (column) I am trying to get the highest number of the fall_value column the id only primary key, the table as following:

| id (P) | fall_value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1.2 | 2021-01-29 |
| 4 | 1.5 | 2021-01-30 |
| 5 | 1.6 | 2021-01-30 |
| 6 | 1 | 2021-01-31 |
| 7 | 5 | 2021-01-31 |
| 8 | 1.5 | 2021-01-31 |
| 9 | 1.5 | 2021-01-31 |
| 10 | 14 | 2021-01-31 |
| 11 | 15 | 2021-01-31 |

expected result: **15**

I have tried the following inquiry:

```
SELECT max(fall_value) from report;
```

I got an unexpected result: **5**

and also I got a message saying:

> **Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available**

Comment: If the `id` is the primary key, why is the value repeated?  Duplicates are not allowed.

Comment: the id is only the primary key the rest not. so the rest of the column values can be dublicted.

Comment: You have 2 10s in id is 1 of them a typo?

Comment: sorry my bad it is typo

Comment: re the message you got, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18922503/17389

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `fall_value` is a string, not a number, and the string "5" is indeed greater than the string "15".

Try converting to a number.  A convenient way is to use implicit conversion:

```
SELECT max(fall_value + 0) 
FROM report;
```