# How to recreate id column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

Well, this is actually a simple question but I can't seem to find a proper answer anywhere else.

I have an id column. The column is empty, but the table contains approximately 11,000 rows. I want the empty id column to be used as the Id. What PHP/SQL code can I run to fill those 11,000 rows of that id column? (like so: '1, 2, 3, 4... ect')

Comment: Drop the existing column then follow this to add a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764/insert-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-database/9070808#9070808

Comment: 'int' and your command doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to drop the old column. You can `MODIFY` it in place with `ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;` and the column will be filled.