# How can I add a unique record number to a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, alter

I have created a table and thought timestamp will be enough to get all records ordered and unique identify-able. My mistake, I got double timestamps.

I want to alter the table to add a record id (Autoincrement) and fill up the old records with that id as well. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert auto increment primary key to existing mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764/insert-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-database)

Comment: If you're running on a local server, and use PhpMyAdmin, go to localhost/PhpMyAdmin, select your table. Click on Structure tab, And you'll notice an Add button on the buttom. This will prompt you to add a new column. You can type-in record id, and check the AI for it. AI means Auto-Increment. And select Unique as its Index

Comment: @LoganWayne That advice is only useful if the OP meets a number of requirements e.g. is running locally and has phpMyAdmin. Admittedly this is very common but it's still not ideal to provide information based on those assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add PK autoincrement field using the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD COLUMN `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

The values of this field for the existing rows will be populated automatically.