# adding ID column with value of 1 to last row of the Exsiting table

Tags: sql-server

I have one existing table called 'x' contains 'n' columns and trying to add one more column called ID which should have value with 1 to 128 (because i have 128 rows) in table.how can i do this using sql.

Comment: If you add additional rows, should it continue incrementing? (I assume so) See [Insert auto increment primary key into existing table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764/insert-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-database/9070808#9070808)

Comment: thanks for hint Michael,since  i am using SQL server IDENTITY do work of AUTO_INCREMENT hence fallowing command works fine . ALTER TABLE tb1 ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY

Comment: Retagging from mysqli to sql server then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **ALTER** query with **IDENTITY(1,1)** for the new column.

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

[Here you get the fiddler help.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6132/1)