# Auto increment null fields, leave non null fields as is

Tags: mysql

I have a table `items` which has a field `priority`. Half of the elements in field priority have a unique value ranging from `1` to `x`. I want the elements where field `priority` is null to have incremental values of `x+1` to `y`.

I have tried

```
UPDATE items
SET priority = IFNULL(priority, 0)
```

but that is not what I want. I want non null fields to stay as is, which I achieved with following:

```
SET priority = IFNULL(priority, 0)
```

and null fields to start being incremented from value, which I get with following:

```
SELECT MAX(priority)
FROM items;
```

So the only thing that comes to mind is something close to

```
UPDATE items
SET priority =
    IFNULL(priority, 0) + (SELECT MAX(priority)
                           FROM items)
WHERE priority IS NULL
```

However I am not too sure how I would go about doing so. Any hints or tips?

Comment: If you are not sure if it will work then just try and see if it worked

Comment: How many do you have? Will you ever have to correct this again, or is it a one-off renumbering? The column does not already have an AUTO_INCREMENT I presume, because it would be null if it didn't. I can see a situation where you [add a new auto_increment column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764/insert-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-database/9070808#9070808) after setting its value to x+1 then updating the old existing values to the new column.  Maybe.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski this is a one off thing. And there are 30 items that have priority set from 1 to 30, and 40 items that have null priority. Column doesn't have auto increment or anything of the kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current maximum priority and store it in a variable.  Then, bring that value into the query, say by using a `cross join`.  You can increment the value in the `set` statement:

```
update items i cross join
       (select @x := max(priority) from items) maxp
    set priority = (@x := @x + 1)
    where priority is null;
```

Comment: @CarlSaldanha I did, and it will be visible once it is peer reviewed. I edited the actual answer and added `from items` in the join part.