# inserting an object column in data array with existing data

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have an existing data array with a format like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100001 [salary] => 346.35416666667 [late_duration] => 2 [undertime_duration] => 3 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-09 )
     [1] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100001 [salary] => 350 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-10 )
     [2] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100002 [salary] => 350 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-09 )
     [3] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100003 [salary] => 358.75 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 2 [date] => 2019-09-09 )
```

now i want to insert a data inside of my existing array to be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100001 [salary] => 346.35416666667 [late_duration] => 2 [undertime_duration] => 3 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-09 [calculate_id] => 1 )
[1] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100001 [salary] => 350 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-10 [calculate_id] => 1 )
[2] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100002 [salary] => 350 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 0 [date] => 2019-09-09 [calculate_id] => 1 )
[3] => Array ( [employee_id] => 14100003 [salary] => 358.75 [late_duration] => 0 [undertime_duration] => 0 [cola_duration] => 2 [date] => 2019-09-09 [calculate_id] => 1 )
```

Here is my code and it returns error: Attempt to assign property `'calculate_id'` of non-object

```
$calculate = $this->payroll->record_calculate_date($start_date,$end_date);

            foreach ($this->data_array as $key => $value) {
                array_push($this->data_array , $this->data_array->calculate_id = $calculate);
            }
            foreach ($$this->data_array1 as $key => $value) {
                array_push($this->data_array , $this->data_array->calculate_id = $calculate);
            }
```

Comment: So I guess your question is "How do I add an "Insert_ID column to my table?"  Suggestion: consider something like [alter table add column insert_id int auto_increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764)

Comment: @paulsm4 i'll edit mo question to be more specific

Comment: @paulsm4 please check my editted question

Comment: is your `employee_id` autoincremented and primary or not? is `not` then just use `$this->db->insert($data)` query to save data

Comment: Q: So what exactly *IS* your question?  Q: What happens when you execute the code in your last snippet?  If your table doesn't already have "insert_id", I imagine you get a MySQL error.  Can you post the error?  Q: If it does, why not just `alter table` and make the column auto_increment (s Gulshan suggests)?

Comment: @paulsm4 please check my data array. something like i want to alter my array and add each row in my array the insert_id of the last inserted data that i've made

Comment: @paulsm4 i've edited my whole question please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_map`

```
$calculate = $this->payroll->record_calculate_date($start_date,$end_date);
$f = array_map(function($v) use ($calculate){
    return $v + ["calculate_id" => $calculate];
}, $this->data_array);
$this->data_array = $f;
```

DEMO : https://3v4l.org/0pJNW

Comment: very great answer. this is what i need

Comment: @Jc John - thank you for clarifying your question.  Notes: 1) it always helps to *ASK A SPECIFIC QUESTON*.  State your question: don't imply it.  2) Example code is great.  3) Copying/pasting the actual error message related to the code is even better.  Lesson learned for your next question :)  Please upvote Rakesh Jakhar if he helped; and please "accept" his answer if it resolved the problem.

Comment: @paulsm4 noted.