# Updating Dual (2-D) Columns Sequentially in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sequential

I have an issue similar to this question:

[updating columns with a sequence number mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617056/updating-columns-with-a-sequence-number-mysql)

However, I have a second column that also "sometimes" needs updated.  For example, consider this table:

```
uID | X | Y
1   | 6 | 0
2   | 2 | 0
3   | 7 | 0
4   | 7 | 1
5   | 3 | 0
6   | 1 | 0
```

I would like 'X' re-ordered sequentially which I can do with the solution from the link, above:

```
SET @rank:=0;  
UPDATE `myTable` SET
X = @rank:= @rank+1
ORDER BY X
```

However, if the record has Y values greater than 0 I need its X to be updated at the same time.  The Y value, being the 2 dimensional value, needs to remain with its 'X'.  Make sense?  So I need the table to end up:

```
uID | X | Y
6   | 1 | 0
2   | 2 | 0
5   | 3 | 0
1   | 4 | 0
3   | 5 | 0
4   | 5 | 1
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SET @rank:=0;  
UPDATE `myTable` SET
X = @rank:= @rank + if(y=0,1,0)
ORDER BY X
```

demo--> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f158e/1