# order and change one column of database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one col in my database named `position` used for ordering. However, when some records is deleted, the sequence get messed up. I want to reorder this col when the table is changed(maybe use trigger).

```
    position(old)    ->  position(new)
       1                    1
       3                    2
       7                    3
       8                    4
```

like this.
I think there will not exist equal number even in position(old), because I have already attach some function in PHP to reorder the column when updates occurs. However, when a record is deleted because of the deletion of its `parent`, function will not be called.

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you are using the column just for ordering, you do not need to update column on deletion, because the order will still be correct. And you will save some resources.

Comment: ...and if you are using it for presentation - you shouldn't, you should use the language you implement this in to generate those numbers by an incrementing variable for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the column just for ordering, you do not need to update column on deletion, because the order will still be correct. And you will save some resources.

But if you really need to update by sequence, look at this answer:

[updating columns with a sequence number mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617056/updating-columns-with-a-sequence-number-mysql)

I believe (as scrowler wrote) the better way in such case is to update rows from the application, after application deletes the parent record.

Comment: SET @rank:=0;
update T
set position=@rank:=@rank+1    order by position

Comment: like this? I need to update because this will be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to update it in the application then...

If position = n is deleted, you logic should be set position = position - 1 where position > n

Please note that this will work only if you delete one record at a time from your application and before assuming that before the delete is triggered the data is already in sequence

Comment: yeah. I have done this already but sometimes record will be deleted because its related record is deleted. I have several tables and other tables will affect this one. In this situation, I cannot trigger my function and also more than one record may be deleted

Comment: If you need it in the trigger, what about to call the update query in the trigger on parent record?