# How to iterate in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

supose I do:

```
select idx from table where number = 1;
```

and this select returns 10 rows (for example) and I want to update the idx column of these 10 rows from 0 to 9. How can I do it?

**UPDATE:**
Here is a query

```
/ orderID / lineID /   q  / idx  /

/   1    /    1    /   1  /  0   /

/   1    /    2    /   1  /  1   /

/   1    /    3    /   1  /  2   /

/   2    /    4    /   1  / null /

/   2    /    5    /   1  / null /

/   2    /    6    /   1  / null /

/   3    /    7    /   1  / null /

/   3    /    8    /   1  / null /
```

And I want to replace the null value of idx as following:

```
/ orderID / lineID /   q  / idx  /

/   1    /    1    /   1  /  0   /

/   1    /    2    /   1  /  1   /

/   1    /    3    /   1  /  2   /

/   2    /    4    /   1  /  0   /

/   2    /    5    /   1  /  1   /

/   2    /    6    /   1  /  2   /

/   3    /    7    /   1  /  0   /

/   3    /    8    /   1  /  1   /
```

Comment: Iterate over what? The question body implies that you just need a simple `UPDATE` DML statement.

Comment: Maybe this one will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617056/updating-columns-with-a-sequence-number-mysql

Comment: The best way to do this is with a [Windowing Function](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/window-functions-in-sql/). In Sql Server, it'd be a `Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` projection. Unfortunately, MySql doesn't support windowing functions, even though they've been part of the ansi sql standard since 2003.

Comment: Do you want to calculate `idx` while you do your select or you want to actually update the table?

Answer (score 0):

for update you can use update query with syntax

```
> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
>     SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
>     [WHERE where_condition]
>     [ORDER BY ...]
>     [LIMIT row_count]
```

[Refrence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

In your case

```
update table SET idx=9 where number = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set idx = rownum where number = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this without the use of windowing functions, which MySql does not support :( All I can do is show you how I'd do it in Sql Server.

First, the basic select query to demonstrate the results you want:

```
SELECT orderID, lineID, q, Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY orderID ORDER BY orderID, lineID) -1 AS idx
FROM `table`
ORDER BY orderID
```

And now turn that into an update query like this:

```
UPDATE t1 set t1.idx = t2.idx
FROM  
(
    SELECT orderID, lineID, q, Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY orderID ORDER BY orderID, lineID) -1 AS idx
    FROM `table`
    ORDER BY orderID
) t2
INNER JOIN `table` t1 ON 
WHERE t1.orderID = t2.orderID AND t1.lineID = t2.LineID AND t1.q = t2.q
```

The trick is that you can only put a windowing function in a SELECT or ORDER BY clause, and so you have to write the projection, and then join that back to the original table via the primary key for the update.

Again, MySql does not support Windowing Functions, even though they've been part of the SQL standard since 2003. I've heard, though, that you can sometimes [work around this via group_concat()](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40203/5469).