# #1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, join

To bypass a problem I posted in a other thread. I tried an sql statement like this:

```
UPDATE user u JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) r
SET user_rank_planets = (@i := (@i + 1))
WHERE user_active=1
ORDER BY user_planets DESC
```

I got Error #1221. Without the order by clause, the statement works fine.
Is there someone who knows a solution for this issue?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You cannot use the order by clause when you have a multi table update statement.

Comment: **user_planets** and **user_rank_planets** are valid columns in the Table **user**

Answer (score 12):

You cannot use order by and limit in update statement in the case of multiple tables.

Quoting From MySQL Documentation:

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named
>   in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is
>   updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For
>   multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

```
UPDATE user u 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    (@i := (@i + 1)) AS row_number
    FROM user u 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) r
    WHERE user_active=1
    ORDER BY user_planets DESC
)AS t
ON u.Primary_key = t.primary_key
SET u.user_rank_planets = t.row_number.
```

**Note:** Replace `u.Primary_key` and `t.primary_key` by the primary key of `user` table.

---

Read first few paragraphs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: the query is valid, but zero rows are affected.

Comment: maybe there's nothing to update. Start with fresh set of data and confirm.

Comment: This doesn't work in MariaDB because ORDER BY is ignored in subqueries. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

Comment: You need LIMIT 2147483647 after ORDER BY inside order query because MySQL and MariaDB will loose order of joined set (will join in random order) if there is no limit specified (When limit is specified MySQL/MariaDB create temp table inside memory for query result under JOIN)

Answer (score 3):

The @1000111's answer doesn't work. I don't know the reason but MySQL just ignored the ORDER BY in the subquery and updated with the default order (by the Primary_key).
A silly solution is wrapping the subquery inside another subquery to create a temporary table.

```
UPDATE user u 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *, (@i := (@i + 1)) AS row_number
        FROM user u 
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) r
        WHERE user_active=1
        ORDER BY user_planets DESC
    ) AS t1
) AS t
ON u.<Primary_key> = t.<Primary_key>
SET u.user_rank_planets = t.row_number
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like they turned off sorting in MySQL8