# Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY In Laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

Iam trying to update 'sortOrder' column based on a given list of ids.
For example, if the given IDs are:

```
$orderList = ['id' =>'1','id' =>'5','id' =>'3']
ID of '1' => 'sortOrder column'  = 1
ID of '5' => 'sortOrder column'  = 2
ID of '3' => 'sortOrder column'  = 3
```

Query statement:

```
 $ids_array = array_pluck($orderList, 'id');
 $ids_string = implode(',', $ids_array);

 DB::statement(DB::raw('set @rownum=0'));

 $result = DB::table('requirements')
                 ->join('sections', 'sections.id', '=', 'requirements.section_id')
                 ->whereIn('id', $ids_array)
                 ->orderByRaw("FIELD(requirements.id, {$ids_string})")
                 ->update([
                     'requirements.sortOrder' => DB::raw('@rownum  := @rownum  + 1'),
                 ]);
```

But when I try to update using this query, I am getting an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1221 Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384009/1221-incorrect-usage-of-update-and-order-by)

Comment: Is there really a need of join with sections table ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yes,  I wanna do something like:    ->where('sections.post_id', $some_id)

Comment: Then you cannot as per docs *For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.*

Comment: is there any alternative way?

Comment: @Devon the duplicate is not using JOIN

Comment: As an alternative i guess you could use `where exists(...)` instead of a join but not sure because haven't tested something like this