# Ordering a database table then numbering a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table which is made for accountancy documents. The table looks like:

```
  id  | doc_number |    doc_date
------|------------|-----------------
  24  |     24     |    1501061817
  25  |     25     |    1501750532
  26  |     26     |    1501750457
```

Let's imagine we delete a record which its doc_number is 25. So now doc_numbers are ..,21,22,23,24,26,27,...  and it's a bad thing that after 24 we have 26 rather than 25.

Through time accountancy documents will be added to and deleted from the table and doc_number has to be continuous.

By some reasons I have to write a php method which synchronizes doc_numbers. the answer is so easy:

```
public function sync(){
  $sql = "SELECT id FROM acc_docs ORDER BY doc_date ASC, id DESC";
  $array = DB::run_query($sql); //a method that runs a query and returns the result as an array of objects
  foreach($array as $key => $object){
    $sql = "UPDATE acc_docs SET doc_number=".($key+1)." WHERE id=".$object->id;
    DB::execute_query($sql); // a method that executes sql queries
  }
}
```

It's obvious that it's not a good practice. What is the best practice for this purpose? What is the best way to write a method that sorts the table and then numbers a column? I have googled for it and found good questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617056/updating-columns-with-a-sequence-number-mysql), but I couldn't find anything which both orders and updates a column.

Comment: I can't see the point of storing this information

Comment: if `id` is primary key then re-indexing will lead you big problem in future (when some other tables are going to use this `id` as a `foreign key` in them)

Comment: There's a contradiction here. `doc_number` probably has to be continuous for a reason, checking that no document was deleted of added. Now you want to intentionally break this? PS: If you want the doc_number you could simply ask: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM acc_docs WHERE id <= targetId`. The date doesn't seem relevant for ordering?

Comment: The answer is in the link you posted. Read the comments, too. But like Strawberry says, what's the point of it? @AlivetoDie it's not about id, it's about doc_number.

Comment: One option here:  Just do a soft delete when your remove a document record.  Now, everything is continuous, but you still know what has been deleted.  Or, generate the sequence at the time you query using session variables.

Comment: @fancyPants  it' all about is that `id/doc_number` is treated as `foreign-key/primary-key` in other table? if yes then OP is going to face problem, if he re-index his current table data

Comment: "and it's a bad thing that after 24 we have 26 rather than 25". Why? If you're just going to keep changing the number, how does it serve as useful information? If you're using it to count the number of rows, you don't need to, you can just use SQL COUNT(). Clearly you're not using it as an identifier, otherwise you wouldn't change it. It's hard to see why the field is even required.

Comment: The document numbers has to be continuous, and through time this rule will be broken (When user deletes a record). Document numbers are shown to users and it's bad to have 23,24,26. I have to write a method  that updates whole table and assigns continuous document numbers according to time they're created. this is the point of it.

Comment: why is this useful to the user? If document 25 used to be document 26, and another document (now deleted) used to be shown as document 25, they might find that confusing. They might assume that document 25 is the same document that was representing by 25 previously (like a unique ID). If it's not being used for that, then what are the users understanding by it? If you just want a sequential list of numbers, you can add that in the UI, no need to make complications to store and maintain it in the DB.

Comment: @ADyson I don't want to go deep to accountancy, but believe it I need such method that updates such column in data base. the whole logic behind it, is the accountants want to see the document numbers as they are. and suddenly one day they decide to reorganize acc_numbers.  The fact is they must be noncontinuous unless they want them to be.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say here. What's the relationship of the acc_number here, and how does reorganising them affect the doc_number? And you say " the whole logic behind it, is the accountants want to see the document numbers as they are." What does "as they are" mean? I would take it to mean that the numbers should be "as they are and always have been", which suggests you shouldn't change them. You haven't explained how a sequential list of document numbers (which could one minute be next to document A, and next minute be next to document B) is useful to anyone.

Comment: @ADyson The accountant creates a record in database. while adding the record he assigns a number to this accountancy document and it's called doc_number in database. (he usually assigns continues numbers ). through time this continuity will be destroyed (deleting a record or maybe himself don't want to assign a continues number to it). One day accountant decides to reassign numbers to doc_numbers. oldest document should have doc_number=1 and the newest document should have the biggest doc_number and these doc_numbers must be continues now.
Believe it or not, I need such method.

Comment: "while adding the record he assigns a number to this accountancy document". There's the root of your problem. Why does the _accountant_ do this? How does he remember if it's unique? How does he know that someone else is not trying to insert a document at that moment with the same number? The _system_ should assign IDs like this. Also, if the accountant assigns the number, why would he want to reassign them? Surely he wants the numbers to refer to specific documents, so he can remember?

Comment: IMHO the business process where a user assigns numbers is faulty - in almost every database system in the world you'll find it's the database which assigns IDs like this, and I still cannot see the purpose of a sequential list of numbers which could change at any moment. You talk about "continuity" of numbers, but I think this is the wrong word. Continuity means "consistency", i.e. "does not change over time". You just want a "continuous", but changeable, list of numbers, which is not the same thing at all, and just literally just that, a list of continuous numbers with no inherent meaning.

Comment: Anyway I've made this same basic point several times now, and so did other commenters earlier. I won't post an answer because I think it's inherently a bad design. You're right that this is not a good practice, but not for the reasons you assumed.

Answer (score 1):

As @KIKO Software said, the doc_number needs to be permanently linked to the original source document so there is a clear audit trail for internal control purposes. These are the reasons:

1. If a record is deleted **the 'gap' in doc_numbers shows the records are not contiguous** and there is a problem.
2. The column name doc_number also suggests it links to another document that is likely to be part of a **business process outside the database**. Updating the doc_number will invalidate this relationship. In short, do not change the doc_number.
3. If a mistake has been made in the production of a source documwnt then do not delete it, but **raise another contra document** to reverse the mistake, that maintains the audit trail and reflects 'normal business' practice.

Also see helpful discussion with @ADyson below.

Comment: yes...although in the example "id" is the same as doc_number and is probably the primary key of the table. If you're arguing that doc_number is being used as a unique identifier, then it's effectively redundant because "id" is doing is already and is also the primary key of the table, therefore that should be used for the purpose.

Comment: I don't want to go deep to accountancy, but believe it I need such method that updates such column in data base. the whole logic behind it, is the accountants want to see the document numbers as they are. and suddenly one day they decide to reorganize acc_numbers. The fact is they must be noncontinuous unless they want them to be.

Comment: @ADyson, from a database perspective I agree, but the doc_number is likely to be used in the business process and the id ignored, so the audit trail will appear contiguous. Also, even if the the id reveals a gap, we have no idea what was deleted or why.

Comment: "the doc_number is likely to be used in the business process"...so then delete the ID column and make doc_number the primary key. It's just a field name. Two fields which do the same thing is pointless. And if the doc_number is being used in the business process, it needs to consistently identify the same document every time, which makes it a unique identifier, which means in turn it should be used as the primary key.

Comment: @ADyson naturalising primary keys into business processes has consequences.

Comment: Such as? Consistency and reliability? What negative consequences can you think of? The whole point of primary keys is to uniquely identify the record.

Comment: @ADyson, I am not saying it is necessarily a bad idea and I did not design the datbase schema, I am just working with what the OP gave us.  However,  in practice the business process may force changes on the key that are difficult or detrimental to the database. For example, we would now like the key to have the year at the end or to change completely. Interesting post on  surrogate keys here: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html

Comment: @ADyson, also unless the database is being set up for a new business process, perhaps a startup, then an existing control number system will exist and need to be reproduced and maintained for seamless operation. In OP example the primary key and doc_number are identical and of similar composition, but how often is that the case in the field. Such number are often concatenated constructions of customer numbers, incrementing numbers, years, countries and more.

Comment: Not necessarily. My company is migrating its accounting system right now and all the entities are being re-numbered. A lookup table is being created during the migration run, showing old IDs and new IDs, and anyone wanting to use an old ID can look it up there - there's an API to it and a GUI for users. All apps etc which used the old IDs as foreign keys / references will get their records updated to the new IDs at go-live based on the lookup tables.

Comment: As for concatenated IDs, they can be used, but should not be used as actual keys and often can be built in the UI instead of stored. Also, if they're made up things which could potentially be changed over the course of a record's existence (e.g. countries as you mention, sounds like a customer could move country) then they're a bad choice for an ID, even if it's not the real internal DB key, if it's the one users refer to it by, then it should be unchangeable.

Comment: @ADyson on the first point about migration. I agree that migration may allow reconfiguration and conversion to a new IDs, but as you say "not necessarily".  On your second point, I agree, that supports my concern about naturalising primary keys.  Continued...

Comment: Continued... In my experience it will often be outside the decision of the IT professional whether IDs can be converted or concatenated keys used. Such decisions are often made by the FD accountant or managers in charge of the business process. Having read through our discussion, I find more that we agree on than disagree on. Schema decisions are often a compromise between IT and business constraints.

Comment: That is certainly true. And it is incumbent on the IT professionals to advise the non-IT professionals about creating consistent and maintainable data structures, and pushing back on flawed or impossible requirements which will create future problems. Hence why I think OP should go back to their boss / client and tell them this is a daft idea.

Comment: @ADyson - I agree OP should go back to their boss/client and explain the issues with the idea. Indeed, that was the essence of my original post. The SO system is trying to automatically move this to chat. Should I do that, or leave as helpful resource?

Comment: I would leave it here for others, including OP, to read, personally.

Comment: @ADyson Will do, thanks, I enjoyed the discussion and think it will be helpful to OP.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you want is a continuous number order by the tables ID. Which begs the question of why you would store this in the database as opposed to generate it when you select thereby always being correct?

```
SET @doc_number=0;
SELECT ID, @doc_number:=@doc_number+1 AS doc_number, doc_date
  FROM acc_docs
  GROUP BY ID
  ORDER BY ID DESC;
```