# Is there a way to get the row number of a record within the result of a query?

Tags: mysql

Let's imagine we have a query like:

```
SELECT id,key1
FROM my_table
WHERE condition = true
ORDER BY id
```

And this gives as a result the following array:

```
[
    [id => 123, key1 => 'A'], 
    [id => 234, key1 => 'B'],
    [id => 546, key1 => 'C']
]
```

The array has 3 values. The index of the row with `key1='B'` is **1**.

Is there a way to get the `'1'` directly from a query?

Comment: Not really. Rows in an RDBMS represent unordered sets. So without an ORDER BY clause, the '2' has no meaning. When you create the array from the query result, your application code arbitrarily assigns an order to the result, but you cannot reasonably deduce the order of the data set from the order of the array, because, as mentioned, there is no order. Makes sense?

Comment: Did you try `SHOW INDEXES` or `SHOW KEYS`?

Comment: If you want `B` as [2], and more generally the nth row from an alphabetical order, add an index on `key1` (if not already) and `ORDER BY key1`. If you want an absolute (always the same `B` => 2, even if `AA` is added, add an `auto_increment` col, and order by that.

Comment: That query wont give that result... So we are kinda stumbling about in the dark here. You have not made it clear what you are actually trying to do and what the table actually looks like

Comment: Updated @RiggsFolly

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using, but basically you can see how in [this tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's what I was looking for @RiggsFolly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617100/532208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to get the positional index of each row in the result set.

```
SELECT id, key1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)
FROM my_table
WHERE condition = true
ORDER BY id
```