# How to update a column with a sequence number for each id?

Tags: mysql

To visualize the issue, let say I have this table:

| book_id | book_running_no |
| --- | --- |
| booka |  |
| booka |  |
| booka |  |
| bookb |  |
| bookb |  |

With column book_running_no just added.

I want to update the table, setting column book_running_no with a sequence number for each book_id and expect the result to be like this:

| book_id | book_running_no |
| --- | --- |
| booka | booka01 |
| booka | booka02 |
| booka | booka03 |
| bookb | bookb01 |
| bookb | bookb02 |

book_running_no = book_id + 2 digit running number

I found the running number solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617056/updating-columns-with-a-sequence-number-mysql), but now I need to custom the number generation for each book_id. The actual table has more than 800k records.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Show the output for `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: 5.1.33-community

Comment: In this ancient version you must use user-defined variables for rows per group enumeration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE test t1
SET book_running_no = CONCAT( book_id,
                              LPAD(CASE WHEN book_id = @id
                                        THEN @num := @num + 1
                                        ELSE @num := 1 
                                        END, 2, 0), 
                              LEFT((@id := book_id), 0)
                              )
ORDER BY book_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bqhGysyM)

Comment: This works! Tqvm sir